# When Infinite Loop is opening at same time in Redhat Linux then how to stop it?

Tags: loops, while-loop, do-while, break, gnome-terminal

when some one attack like DDOS or Dos in our computer

for example someone like hacker let's say run infinite loop in your terminal to open the gnome-terminal

**code**:--

while :
do
gnome-terminal
done

that time you not have time to stop them because the cursor is move into next to next terminal and you can not type single word at that time to kill that all terminal.

So what i can do ??

I tried multiple way but the only way i can imagine is we can not write single word into the terminal
so we have to think that how we can stop that terminal without writing a command into the terminal

Right ??

Comment: I think I just had a stroke reading this

Answer (score -1):

When this happens, you just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>.
After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, a pop-up will come up and, in that command prompt window, you just have to type:

```
pkill gnome-terminal
```